navbar dropdown buttons is not working properly
I am trying to make a navigation bar. It consists of 2 parts: A bar for wide screens(desktop 900px and up) and a mobile bar(900px and lower)(this part works). The problem is when i try to nest dropdown buttons inside a dropdown menu. the buttons won't line up with the other buttons and the dropdown content is not in it's own "container". It should have it's own square not inhabit / be on top of the previeus dropdown.
Link to the page:  https://groundfaultsystems.com/3d-dgf18.html
The problem should be between < !--mobile navbar  -->< !-- not working properly--> and < !--mobile navbar   end-->
My expectation was:
Hover over te first button then you get a dropdown menu.(works)
Dropdown menu: all the buttons line up neatly.(nowere close)
dropdown content for the dropdown buttons in this menu are not visable until i hover them.(still visable)
the dropdown content for the dropdown buttons is not overlapping the first dropdown menu.(overlaps the menu)
I have been wrestling with this for a few days now, i don't exactly know anymore what i tried and why it did not work. I'm lost. Can someone point me in the right direction
